# HTTP Form is appending URL instead of redirecting

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, gatsby

This just recently started happening and I haven't changed anything in my form code to cause a problem, previously when clicking the submit button for the form it would POST the data to the action URL and redirect the user. Instead now it redirects me to `https://my.current.domain/my/path/https://action.com`

Here's how the form is rendered:

```
    <form
      method="post"
      action="​https://checkout.simplexcc.com/payments/new"
      target="_self"
      className="hidden-form"
    >
      {Object.keys(formData).map((key, index) => {
        const value = formData[key];
        return <input key={key} type="hidden" name={key} value={value} />;
      })}
      <button
        id="submit"
        type="submit"
      />
    </form>
```

So for example, when running my dev server I am getting redirected to

http://localhost:8000/https://checkout.simplexcc.com/payments/new

Instead of

https://checkout.simplexcc.com/payments/new

Comment: Somehow `localhost:port` is being appended to your url request. Have you tried playing around with the value you're providing to the `action` property? You say you haven't changed anything, but have you changed any `<Route>` declarations lately or whatever you use for navigation?

Comment: @DJ2 No, I have not changed any routing. The only changes I made between this build and the last one were styling changes. It just started doing this on this build. Basically, instead of submitting the form to the 3rd party website, it's using the action as a relative path for my own website. So https://google.com/https://checkout.simplexcc.com/payments/new would be a production example of what's happening.

Comment: I should clarify that if I go back to my last commit it's still doing this, even though it was working on the build for the last commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an invisible UTF8 character between the quote and the letter h in the snipped you posted.

[image: hex view]